# What are the options of using scoped variables in grails?

Tags: session, grails

In my grails service I have a variable that stores some **JSON** obtained by fetching data from web service. I would like to make that variable unique for every user of the app. I am guessing i would need to move that variable to controller and use `session[]` to make it happen or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a separate instance of the variable per user of the application, you could either store it in the session, or make the service session-scoped (they are singletons by default) and store it in the service.

```
class MyService {
    static scope = 'session'

}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a service class to hold a single value, be sure to add `static transactional = false` to make it as lightweight as possible.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith personally, I'd prefer the session approach to the service

Comment: How do you inject session scoped service into regular singleton ones?